# intercept value during JSON to Object using GSON

Tags: android, gson

I have the following setup:

```
public static class MyPojoImpl {
    @SerializedName("myNumber")
    private int myNumber;
    @SerializedName("myType")
    private String myType;

    @Override
    public List<String> getMyNumber() {
        return myNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public @Type String getMyType() {
        return myType;
    }

    @StringDef({Type.ONE,
            Type.TWO,
            Type.THREE})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @interface Type {
        String ONE = "ONE";
        String TWO = "TWO";
        String THREE = "THREE";
    }
}
```

I have a string value `myType` that comes from JSON. I'd like to restrict this string value only to certain values. Is there any way to intercept `myType` before it's set to my object?

I know that I can achieve this by converting to `type` to enum, but I'd like to avoid using enums altogether. Alternatively, I could also put checking logic in getter, but that's not too efficient.

Jackson allows using setters. Is there something similar in GSON?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can customise the deserialise process by implementing `JsonDeserializer`

[Ref here for Complete Example](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-serialiser-example/)

```
private class DateTimeDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<MyPojoImpl> {
  public MyPojoImpl deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
      throws JsonParseException {
        MyPojoImpl pojoImpl = new MyPojoImpl();
        // Do the Processing here
        return pojoImpl
  }
}

GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
gson.registerTypeAdapter(MyPojoImpl.class, new DateTimeDeserializer());
```